# meaning of -‌- in git checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

If I want to replace a folder on a working branch with the same folder from another branch,
I can call:

```
 git checkout OTHER_BRANCH -- /path/to/folder
```

what is the meaning of the --   ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything after `--` is considered a file name. This is useful in at least two cases:

1. same name for a file and branch. Note the difference between `git checkout foo --` and `git checkout -- foo`
2. filenames which could be interpreted as flag: `git checkout -- -f` (alternatively: `git checkout ./-f`